# Pass arguments to .bat file from aws config file

Tags: batch-file, aws-cli

My config file contains:

```
[profile test]
credential_process = batchfile.bat --tcws_url https://tcwsadminsvc-uat.web-dev.bms.com/renew?appId=test1&appRole=test2
```

When I execute `aws s3 ls --profile test` command, `batchfile.bat` command must execute which takes the parameters from `--tcws_url` and the entire endpoint url.

But i'm able to get only `--tcws_url https://tcwsadminsvc-uat.web-dev.bms.com/renew?appId=test1` and not `&appRole=test2`. That is `&` has become the delimiter.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: escape the `&` with a caret. like so: `^&`

Comment: tried that. did not work

Comment: did not work as in? same result?

Comment: Please can you show me the batch file content as well?

Comment: Content of .bat file:     @echo off 
echo %* > test.txt

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this:

Change your batch code to accept the variable to:

```
@echo off
echo %~1 %~2>test.txt
```

Then change your config file to include the caret and double quote your URL:

```
--tcws_url "https://tcwsadminsvc-uat.web-dev.bms.com/renew?appId=test1^&appRole=test2"
```

Comment: This works but it removes the key after & till =. Which means if my url is "https://test.com/?abc=def^&ghi=jkl", %~1 gives https://test.com/?abc=de, %~2 is empty, %~3 is jkl

Comment: Try it as it is now please.